# jQuery: Magic of "submit" event

Tags: jquery, events, button, input, submit

This is simple html:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="default_action" value="default_action_value" />
    <input type="text" name="count" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Button!" />
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="action" value="action value">Button 2!</button>
</form>
```

and js code:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {$(document).ready(function($){
    var $doc = $(document);
    $doc.on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        console.log('submit form!');        
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    .on('click', 'form', function (e) { 
        console.log('click on form (propagation)!');
    })
    .on('click', 'form :submit', function (e) {
        console.log('click on button!');
    });
});})(this, document, jQuery);
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/44YsY/2/)

When I click on the any submit button, in console appears the next messages:

> click on button!
>
> click on form (propagation)!
>
> submit form!

Yeah, ok. As planned. But when set cursor into the text field and press "Enter" (not clicked to the button), console messages:

> click on form (propagation)!
>
> click on button!
>
> click on form (propagation)!
>
> submit form!

o_O? WTF?! Submit button was not clicked! This is the very magic for me..

Now remove submit buttons from html:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="default_action" value="default_action_value" />
    <input type="text" name="count" value="1" />
</form>
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/44YsY/3/)

And trying submit form by the "Enter" button. Console log:

> click on form (propagation)!
>
> submit form!

That are expected to see in the previous example. But why jQuery fires event 'click' for first found submit button?

My initial task is the define source of 'submit' event - click on the submit button or press "Enter". But how to do it, if jQuery fires 'click' on submit button when really pressed "Enter"? How? Why?

Comment: It's not jquery [not jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/zandroid/Vedh5/29/) fault. So it makes the browser :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is according the the latest HTML5 specification.

Pressing 'Enter' on  you trigger 'click' event on the first positioned element, which is why you see the click event fired only once for one of the buttons.

If you need to not trigger the click event on the buttons when pressing enter in the form, you could filter out the ENTER key event in the inputs keypress event

```
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function (e) {
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit(); 
    }
});
```

There are other workarounds, like using the 'button' element type (and hooking up the click event to do a form submit) instead of using the "input" with type submit. Changing the type="submit" to type="button" would also prevent the click from being fired on submit.